# Check if string value is present within array and return found array value(s) js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have key identifiers that look like this...

```
const category = key; // could be "bus","car","plane"
```

for this example lets go with `"bus"`. I also have an array of strings that look like this...

```
let transportationFields = [
      'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus'
      'car', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model',
      'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop',
    ];
```

Right now I'm grabbing the index of

```
const transFieldValues = transportationFields.indexOf(category) > -1;
```

But that just returns `true`. How can I also grab the field it matched to? For example. Since `category = bus`. How can I return all the values it threw true to? (`'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus'`) ?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for finding all matches and return them in an array:

```js
let transportationFields = [
  'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus',
  'car', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model',
  'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop',
];

let category = 'bus';

let transFieldValues = transportationFields.filter(function (item) {
  return item.indexOf(category) > -1;
});

document.write (JSON.stringify(transFieldValues));
```

Or with ES6 arrow function:

```js
let transportationFields = [
  'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus',
  'car', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model',
  'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop',
];

let category = 'bus';

let transFieldValues = transportationFields.filter(w => w.indexOf(category) > -1);

document.write (JSON.stringify(transFieldValues));
```

If you don't mind leaving Edge users out of luck, then you can use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
let transFieldValues = transportationFields.filter(w => w.includes(category));
```

... which just looks nicer than this `> -1` you have to use with `.indexOf()`.

Comment: I think you've got the right answer, i'm just trying to reproduce the syntax is react

Comment: `transportationFields.filter(text => text.includes(category))`

Comment: The Edge browser does not support `includes()`. But who cares ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let transportationFields = [
  'bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus',
  'car', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model',
  'train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop',
];

transportationFields = transportationFields.filter(e => {
  return e.indexOf('bus') != -1;
});

console.log(transportationFields)
```

You can also create a function and pass value to search

```js
let transportationFields = ['bus_station', 'bus_stop', 'bus_line', 'took_bus','car', 'buyer_of_car', 'car_model','train_number', 'train_trip_num', 'train_stop'];

var findField = function(input) {
  return transportationFields.filter(e => {return e.indexOf(input) != -1;});
}

console.log(findField('bus'));
```